# asp.net c# Facebook login difficulties

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-login

Thanks for all,
 i found bug, on server security turn off Facebook APP Blocking

I have a login button problem, if i test it on localhost, it works nice. But when OAuth redirects to host, SERVER ERROR;
I changed my Valid OAuth redirect URIs from http://localhost/ to webURL and Site URL from localhost to http://myweb.url
my server side code :

```
    string fbID ;
    string name ;
    string lName;
    string email;
    string img;


   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
        foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = item.NavigateUrl.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        LP.Visible = false;

        FaceBookConnect.API_Key = "114328XXXXXXXXXX";
        FaceBookConnect.API_Secret = "b24ed5f052bfxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["error"] == "access_denied")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('User has denied access.')", true);
                return;
            }

            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            {

                string data = FaceBookConnect.Fetch(code, "me?fields=id,email,last_name,first_name");
                FaceBookUser faceBookUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<FaceBookUser>(data);
                faceBookUser.PictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", faceBookUser.Id);

                fbID = faceBookUser.Id;
                name  = faceBookUser.first_name;
                lName = faceBookUser.last_name;
                email = faceBookUser.Email;
                img  = faceBookUser.PictureUrl;
}
}
}

 protected void ButtonLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FaceBookConnect.Authorize("user_photos,email", Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0]);
    }
 public class FaceBookUser
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string PictureUrl { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object.]
ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI.FaceBookConnect.?12?(WebException ?26?) +101
ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI.FaceBookConnect.?8?(String ?23?) +287
ASPSnippets.FaceBookAPI.FaceBookConnect.Fetch(String ?16?, String ?17?) +202
SlotMascineOnline.login.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +756
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, 
EventArgs e) +51
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +59
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, 
Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: IP Restriction on the API call on FB's side?

Comment: I not use a IP Restriction

Comment: Thanks for all,
 i found bug, on server security, turn off Facebook APP Blocking